# Best strategy for this game

Tags: game-theory

What would be the best strategy for the following game?

One of the two players starts by transferring $x$ points to the other player. The second player then either keeps the $x$ points or gives back $2x$ points. The game continues, each time doubling the amount of points, until one player decides to keep all the points. This is repeated until a limit of $n$ rounds is reached. The objective is to finish the game with the largest point difference possible.

The game would also be equivalent to "Two players each give a natural number, the lowest number, $a$, wins. The winner receives $2^a$ points."

How would the best strategy change if:

- There are more than two players
- The amount of points increases linearly instead of exponentially (each player gives back $x + 1$ points, or $a$ points are received instead of $2^a$ in the equivalent version of the game)
- Each player can choose how many points to give back (something other than $2x$)
- The game ends once a player reaches a certain number of points rather than a round limit
- In the equivalent game of naming a number $a$, the players can also name a positive real number $a$, rather than just a natural number

Comment: When you give the equivalent version, the strategy giving the best expectancy seems to be : "don't play" :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS: Why wouldn't you play? You're not risking anything and have a chance to win $2^a$ points?

Comment: By "points", I assumed you meant "coins". Then by playing one turn, you loose $x$ dollars, end of story, no ?

Comment: Why would anybody transfer points in this game?

Comment: By giving points, the other player might give back $2x$ points, hoping that you'll give back $4x$ points since you're hoping he'll give back $8x$ points, and so on

Comment: You write an equivalence, but the two games seem distinctly different - in particular, the version which has players giving money back and forth is zero-sum.

Comment: The change in point difference between the winner and loser is $2^a - - 2^{-a}$ if $a$ rounds are played, which is equivalent to the winner winning $2^{(a+1)}$ points and the loser losing nothing.

Comment: This is a version of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede_game.